# DevDemon Tagger Related Image Entries

Tags: devdemon, devdemon-tagger

Having difficulties pulling back the correct image for related entries. It's pulling back the same image as the main entry and not the related entries image.

```
{exp:channel:entries
channel="{news_channel}"
dynamic="no"
limit="3"
url_title="{segment_2}"
parse="inward"
}

{exp:tagger:related entry_id="{tagger:entry:id}" url_title="{segment_2}" custom_fields="news-heading|news-summary"}

    <img src="{news-thumbnail:medium}" alt=" "/>
    <h2>{tagger:news-heading}</h2>
    {tagger:news-summary}{/exp:trunchtml}</p>

{/exp:tagger:related}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Tried using {tagger:news-thumbnail:medium} also but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all custom fields will work. Unfortunately several fieldtypes rely on secondary tables in the db. You will need to embed another entries tag to make it work. For example:

```
    {exp:channel:entries
channel="{news_channel}"
dynamic="no"
limit="3"
url_title="{segment_2}"
parse="inward"
}

{exp:tagger:related entry_id="{entry_id}" url_title="{segment_2}" custom_fields="news-heading|news-summary"}

    {embed="news/.related" id="{tagger:entry_id}"}

{/exp:tagger:related}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then on your .related template

```
 {exp:channel:entries channel="news" entry_id="{embed:id}" dynamic="no"}
    <img src="{news-thumbnail:medium}" alt=" "/>
    <h2>{tagger:news-heading}</h2>
    {tagger:news-summary}{/exp:trunchtml}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Also you had {tagger:entry_id} in your inner loop, not sure how your code worked at all.

Brad

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Brad, much appreciated :)

For reference I needed to remove the tagger: off the custom fields in the embed for them to show. But all working :)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" entry_id="{embed:id}" dynamic="no"}
    <img src="{news-thumbnail:medium}" alt=" "/>
    <h2>{news-heading}</h2>
    {news-summary}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```